# How to set interval on y-axis in flutter charts?

Tags: flutter, charts

Here's my code. I have a graph ranging values from 110-130. I need to set my y-axis from 100-140 not from 0-140. Anyone out there , please help me. I have attached my code below. I'm new to flutter.I have used desired tickcount property, it doesn't helped me. Is there any way to set bounds not just for y-axis but both the axis.

```dart
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleTimeSeriesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
      behaviors: [
        charts.SlidingViewport(
          charts.SelectionModelType.action,
        ),
        charts.PanBehavior(),
      ],
      primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        tickProviderSpec: new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
          desiredTickCount: 10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  static List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {
    List<TimeSeriesSales> data1 = [];
    List<TimeSeriesSales> data2 = [];
    var index = 0;
    for (var item in DataMarket) {
      data1.insert(index++, TimeSeriesSales(item['date'], item['market']));
    }
    index = 0;
    for (var item in DataMarket) {
      data2.insert(index++, TimeSeriesSales(item['date'], item['NAV']));
    }
    print(data1);
    return [
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales1',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        measureLowerBoundFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales - 5,
        measureUpperBoundFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales + 5,
        data: data1,
      ),
      new charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>(
        id: 'Sales2',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data2,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample time series data type.
class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime time;
  final double sales;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this property to your chart:

```
primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(tickProviderSpec:
                new charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false))
```

Full example:

```
charts.LineChart(seriesList,primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                 tickProviderSpec:charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false)))
```